# Problems with Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I am having some problems with Dropbox. I have installed it but it doesn't open.

There also a bad icon on that top

What can I do ?

[image]

Comment: But no way to selective Dropbox sync?

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue which effects several applications. To fix it edit the `~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop` file and change the `Exec` line to this:

`Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE="" dropbox start -i`

Log out and back in and the icon should be correct. I have noticed that even with this the menu sometimes does not appear correctly, but usually a second click will work.

My complete `.desktop` file:

`[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dropbox
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE="" dropbox start -i
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true`

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have added my complete .desktop, in case I missed something. Hope it helps, it has worked for me for a long time.

Comment: Hey ! I have checked and it works now. Thank you very very much rdanter !!

Comment: Could you mark the answer as correct? I need more reputation points so I can comment on other questions :)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer has worked until I restart my system. But this script is working for me permanently

```
https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox
```